# Objective-C — different versions of the same library results in name collisions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, namespaces, compiler-errors

I read Objective–C can easily lead to name collisions due it's nature, so it is a best–practice to prefix your code.

How do you solve this issue if your `MyAwesomeApp` iOS application which is using two external libraries `FooLibrary` and `BarLibrary` results name collisions, because internally also `FooLibrary` happens to use `BarLibrary`?

At first one might suggest to remove either one of the references to `BarLibrary`, but you can't do that, because although both are `BarLibrary`, they are actually two different versions of it, so `FooLibrary` depends on `BarLibrary(v1)` implementation whereas your `MyAwesomeApp` depends on `BarLibrary(v2)` implementation.

At this point I realized two distinct versions of the same library are two different things really and so they shouldn't co–exist in the same project in the first place.

Is there any other way of solving this puzzle other than refactoring (by renaming things) someone else's code please?

Comment: Can you switch to using `v1` of `BarLibrary`?

Comment: I think the only good solution is to get the author of FooLibrary to update to v2 of BarLibrary. This is just one of the limitations we have to live with due to Apple's non-support of shared libraries on iOS.

Comment: @Mike meaning you can't do that?

Comment: @exalted, not unless you have a way to edit the binaries to change the names of the symbols post-compilation. Maybe some kind of obfuscation tool could do it. Or you could use a hex editor and search and replace the offending symbols in both v1 of BarLibrary, and their callers in FooLibrary, with some alternate names. If you do this, be sure to test it well. ;-)

Comment: @exalted, do you have the source code to both FooLibrary and BarLibrary v1? You could also `#define` the function names to something else in their headers...

Comment: @Mike well i guess post–compilation thing is way too unstable, I would rather rename things pre–compilation if I really have to. Also, can you tell a bit more about the `#define`–solution please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the other library is using a library that is likely to be shared, e.g. a JSON library, and they are compiling a library for you to include, then they should really put their own prefixes on the library.

I've seen it done this way with Urban Airship, for example. They use JSONKit (or some JSON library), but they prefix all the JSONKit usages with UA - so that when I use a different version of JSONKit, they compile and run together.

I've also seen it done with Reachability ... everyone seems to have their own version of this...